# Not calling Cluster.close() with the Cassandra Java driver causes application to be "zombie" and not exit

Tags: scala, cassandra, netty, datastax-java-driver

When my connection is open, the application won't exit, this causes some nasty problems for me (highly concurrent and nested using a shared sesssion, don't know when each part is finished) - is there a way to make sure that the cluster doesn't "hang" the application?

For example here:

```
object ZombieTest extends App {
  val session= Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build().connect()
// app doesn't exit unless doing:
session.getCluster.close() // won't exit unless this is called
}
```

Comment: Which concurrency primitive are you using, `Future`? Scala provides many mechanisms to deal with  this problem: `highly concurrent and nested using a shared sesssion, don't know when each part is finished`.

Comment: its called from a spark java job which is very complex and hard to change

Answer (score 0):

In a slightly biased answer, you could look at https://github.com/outworkers/phantom instead of using the standard java driver.

- You get `scala.concurrent.Future`, `monix.eval.Task` or even `com.twitter.util.Future` from a query automatically. You can choose between all three.
- DB connection pools are better isolated inside `ContactPoint` and `Database` abstraction layers, which have `shutdown` methods you can easily wire in to your app lifecycle.
- It's far faster than the Java driver, as the serialization an de-serialisation of types is wired in compile time via more advanced macro mechanisms.

The short answer is that you need to have a lifecycle way of calling `session.close` or `session.closeAsync` when you shut down everything else, it's how it's designed to work.